# Handing over unicode strings to javascript with jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, unicode, jinja2

I am using GAE and at some stage I decode a UTF8 string to then hand it over to an HTML file with Jinja2:

```
  for i in report:
        unique_channels.append(i[0][j].decode("utf8"))

    template_values = {
        "unique_channels" : unique_channels,
        "result" : result
    }
```

Now, when I use Jinja2 to iterate over this list of unicode strings, all is good. But when I pass this list to Javascript, Javascript throws an unexpected string error. I assume the reason is the u'xxx'/Unicode strings.

```
var unique_channels = {{ unique_channels }};

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
   new_data.push({"Position" : i.toString()})
    for (var k = unique_channels.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
      new_data[i-1][unique_channels[k]] = 0;
    } 
};
```

How do I avoid this? Should I pass the list to javascript in a different way? Any suggestions?

EDIT: Second part where I use the unique_channels list:

```
{% for j in unique_channels %}
<br><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="{{ j }}" value="{{ j }}" onclick="updateData();" checked> {{ j }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will be treated as string when I use json.dumps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize the data using [`json.dumps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) before pass to the template:

```
  for i in report:
        unique_channels.append(i[0][j].decode("utf8"))

    template_values = {
        "unique_channels" : json.dumps(unique_channels),
        "result" : result
    }
```

And use [`safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#safe) filter in the template to prevent escape:

```
var unique_channels = {{ unique_channels|safe }};

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
   new_data.push({"Position" : i.toString()})
    for (var k = unique_channels.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
      new_data[i-1][unique_channels[k]] = 0;
    } 
};
```

Comment: json.dumps creates a string though, doesn't it? So if I iterate over this, I'll get the letters of the string, not the strings in the list. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: @oliver13, If you use the passed `unique_channels` in other place in the template, pass non-serialized version also.

Comment: @oliver13, In javascript, `unique_channels` is an array, not a string. Check it out.

Comment: @oliver13, I mean: `template_values = {"unique_channels_py": unique_channels, "unique_channels": json.dumps(unique_channels), "result" : result}`

Comment: Ok, makes sense... still this throws me an unexpected end of input for the var unique_channels = unique_channels|safe. Any idea what this could relate to?

Comment: @oliver13, Could you post another separated question with the traceback?